# how to display all the players username connected to a room in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js

It is a real-time multiplayer game in which a maximum of 2 users can connect to a room.The players are authenticated using passport.js and using express-sessions. I have a question that how to display both the players username to both the players connected to the room.
I can render only one player username to the html file.How to display both the user's name?

when a user visits the website,he logins with his credentials and they are directed to a home page which doesn't starts the game.it has a button to it start the game and when a user clicks on the button it is directed to the game

All the other functionalities including athentication and authorization is working perfectly, only that i am unable to display both the player's username to the players connected in a room.

What logic shall i use?Shall i use express-socket.io-sessions?

Comment: This is a bit too broad but: When a user joins a room - send all usernames (over the socket) to all users that are currently in the room - then manipulate the html page with JavaScript in order to display it in the page.

Comment: yeah. .i know this part.. but how to access the usernames?

Comment: when a user visits the website,he logins with his credentials and they are directed to a home page which doesnt starts the game.it has a button to it start the game and when a user clicks on the button it is directed to the game

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Please help! as i am stuck on this part